# Grid Index Features in ArcMap DDP not labeling consecutively

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-driven-pages

Using Carto tool-->DDP-->Grid Index features - the generated grid doesn't name the tiles consecutively.

The base was around a buffer of a road feature dataset so it's not a rectangular grid.

So it starts with A3-A7, then B1-B5 etc. While understanding that this is logical, is it possible to sequentially number the existing grids?

[image]